# Using stringBuilder to convert strings?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to create a StringBuilder object that contains the first String which are composed of lower case letters converted to uppercase.

Here's what I have tried:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lowerCase = new String("a, b, c, d, e");
        String upperCase = new String("A, B, C, D, E");
        StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(buildString.insert(0, upperCase));
    }
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to convert the first string `lowerCase` into `upperCase`, without using `buildString.insert(_)`, as `.append()` would not work effectively for me.

Comment: Does `lowerCase.toUpperCase();` not work?

Comment: @iota I'm not familiar with this approach, though it works perfectly for me. I'll make consistent use of this from now on. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Although, how would this be done using StringBuilder?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You could use `new StringBuilder(lowerCase.toUpperCase()).toString()`, but that is quite redundant. (Or `buildString.append(lowerCase.toUpperCase())`.)

Comment: @iota I get the error ```cannot convert from string to StringBuilder```, when I replace my `StringBuilder` above as ```StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder(lowerCase.toUpperCase()).toString();```, perhaps I approached this wrongly?

Comment: `StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder(lowerCase.toUpperCase())` works, but why are you using a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: The second option works just how I wanted!

Comment: @iota I'm working through a book that gave this as an exercise. So, right now I'm just trying to work towards building my 'java-lexicon', and applications. Until I can effectively reason well towards the practicality of java.

Comment: StringBuilder is largely irrelevant now. Java's internal String handling changed over the years. Sage advice from 15 years ago is no longer valid.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I am sure I could find several. You could too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `String#toUpperCase` method.

```
String lowerCase = "a, b, c, d, e";
String result = lowerCase.toUpperCase();
```

If you need a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder buildString = new StringBuilder(lowerCase.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal method:

```java
$ jshell
Apr 17, 2021 5:03:10 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 15.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> String lowerCase = new String("a, b, c, d, e");
lowerCase ==> "a, b, c, d, e"

jshell> lowerCase.toUpperCase();
$7 ==> "A, B, C, D, E"
```

Shortest method:

```java
jshell> "a, b, c, d, e".toUpperCase();
$8 ==> "A, B, C, D, E"
```

Overly complex method:

```java
jshell> new StringBuilder("a, b, c, d, e").toString().toUpperCase();
$9 ==> "A, B, C, D, E"
```